# React Native Authentication With NextJs and NextAuth

Tags: react-native, authentication, mobile, next.js, next-auth

I have a website with authentication built with Next.js, NextAuth, Prisma and MySQL.

Now I want to code a React Native app for this website but I am not sure how to make authentication. Can I use the API I already have in next.js app? Or should I use a different way to setup authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at this too and from what I can tell if you want to do more than Next you need to do a different authentication setup.

The one that is getting a lot of attention and supports different platforms is Clerk (clerk.com).

If you want something that's well established take a look at Firebase Auth (Google Identity Platform).

Comment: Thanks for your response! I couldn't find many people doing the same setup so I agree with you. I will take a look at other options

Comment: Just to add there is another that's starting to gain some attention called Kinde.  www.kinde.com.  looks pretty good also.